# Selecting a child tag of a class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I've search the jquery site for this ...and I just can't find it.

I'm trying to select `<p>` tags in a `.desc` class...

```
<div class = "desc">
   <p>blahwhatever</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying make sure `<p></p>` does not display till my animation of `.desc` is done...

```
$(".desc p").hide();
//animation here...
$(".desc p").delay(500).show();
```

This hasn't worked yet... any suggestions?
(Sorry for the trivial question..)

Comment: @Bolt thought that might be a typo, but that would certainly make things not ever work forever

Comment: Just a typo.. what I have was just an example .. sorry - fixed

Comment: Hasn't worked how? Doesn't hide it or doesn't show it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get things working as you would want add the show into the `animate()` methods callback try this:

```
$(".desc p").hide(); 

$('#animationSelector').animate(
    { /* animation settings */},
    5000, 
    function() {
        $(".desc p").show(); 
    }
);
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/X3qkH/

Comment: yes adding it in a ready event hehe. :) What I gave was an example snip of what i'm doing.

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution here is, to pass a value (`0` is absolutly fine) into `.show()`.

```
$(".desc p").delay(500).show(0);
```

This makes sure, that it's added to the **fx queue** and therefore, `.delay()` will take effect.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/MuZMa/1/

Without the value, `.show()` will just trigger a `display: block` immediately.

Comment: Why would this get a down-vote? Too clever for some people? @jAndy: +1 I love seeing this hack.

Comment: @patrick dw: You just beat me to a "why the downvote?" comment. It's over for me.

Comment: wasn't me! I'll give you +1 to make the downer feel terrible

Comment: Don't worry @hunter. You weren't a suspect. Just don't leave town. ;o)

Comment: wasn't me either. Both these solutions worked. But I chose the one below cause it better suited my needs. :) ty though!